# What is the best way to store and query a very large number of variable-length lists in a MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

Maybe this question will be made more clear through an example. Let's say the dataset I'm working with is a whole bunch (several gigabytes) of variable-length lists of tuples, each associated with a unique ID and a bit of metadata, and I want to be able quickly retrieve any of these lists by its ID.

I currently have two tables set up more or less like this:

```
TABLE list(
  id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, 
  flavor VARCHAR, 
  type VARCHAR, 
  list_element_start INT, 
  list_element_end INT)

TABLE list_element(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  value1 FLOAT, 
  value2 FLOAT)
```

To pull a specific list out of the database I currently do something like this:

```
SELECT list_element_start, list_element_end FROM list WHERE id = 'my_list_id'
```

Then I use the retrieved `list_element_start` and `list_element_end` values to get the list elements:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM list_element 
  WHERE id BETWEEN(my_list_element_start, my_list_element_end)
```

Of course, this works very fast, but I feel as though there's a better way to do this. I'm aware that I could have another column in list_element_end called list_id, and then do something like `SELECT * FROM list_element WHERE list_id = 'my_list_id' ORDER BY id`. However, it seems to me that having that extra column, as well as a foreign key index on that column would take up a lot of unnecessary space.

Is there simpler way to do this?

Apologies if this question has been asked before, but I was unable to locate the answer. I'd also like to use SQLAlchemy in Python to do all of this, if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why won't a simple join suffice?

Comment: You can use blob to save space but managing them (modify, delete) will surfer.

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize each element of your array into a row. The following is the declarative style in SQLAlchemy that will give you a "MyList" object with flavor etc, and then elements will be an actual Python list of each "MyElement" object. You could get more complicated to weed out the extra id and idx within the returned element list, but this should be plenty fast enough.

Also, above, you had mixed varchar and int for your primary key, not sure if it was just oversight, but you ought not do that. Additionally, when handling large data sets remember options like chunking. You can use offset and limit to work with smaller sizes and process iteratively.

```
class MyList(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_list'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    flavor = Column(String)
    list_type = Column(String)
    elements = Relationship('my_element', order_by='my_element.idx')

class MyElement(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_element'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('my_list.id'))
    idx = Column(Integer)
    val = Column(Integer)
    __table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint('id','idx'), )
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. Did you mean for the foreign key in MyElement to be on 'my_list.id'? I get errors about not having foreign keys linking the tables if I leave it as 'my_element.id'. If so, then doesn't this create a column that contains the pointer to the list id of each specific list element, as well as a rather large index on it for quick lookup?

Comment: This is how relational databases are designed to work. There are no additional indexes here, just one index for each primary key (which is required anyway). Not sure how you could do better than that.

Answer (score 0):

between is not a function so I don't know what you think is going on there. Anyway... Why not:

```
SELECT e.* 
  FROM list_element e
  Join list l
   On l.id between e.my_list_element_start and my_list_element_end
```

Or am I missing something